# mysql error 1607 - rescuing orphaned database

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1, mediawiki, bitnami

I use mediawiki made available on my Win 8.1 machine through a "Bitnami stack". I accidentally deleted my entire database, but was able to rescue it using an undelete utility. (I don't know if it was rescued properly, as some of the mysql-bin files were reported as "Poor" by the undelete) but the ib_logfile1 seems ok.

So, right now I have this mysql data folder containing all this data I am interested in, but I don't know how to access it (and I don't even know if it got rescued properly, and thus needs to be repaired).

I installed a new clean copy of mediawiki (using Bitnami) on my machine.

If I use the mysql\data folder from this new install, mediawikiMySQL service starts up fine. If I rename this folder to mysql\data-Original, and then copy my rescued data folder into its place, I can no longer startmediawikiMySQL service. I get error 1067, and I don't even know what that means.

How do I go about giving me access to my rescued database?

here is an error log entry from the .err file:

```
150205 22:05:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
150205 22:05:59  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
150205 22:05:59  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Error: all log files must be created at the same time.
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: All log files must be created also in database creation.
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: If you want bigger or smaller log files, shut down the
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: database and make sure there were no errors in shutdown.
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: Then delete the existing log files. Edit the .cnf file
150205 22:05:59 InnoDB: and start the database again.
150205 22:05:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150205 22:05:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150205 22:05:59 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: unknown option '-d'
150205 22:05:59 [ERROR] Aborting

150205 22:05:59 [Note] mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Thanks,
a1

Comment: where is your datapath pointing? Have you tried using innodb recovery flag?

Comment: What file do I go to to figure out my "datapath" - my.ini? There I see `datadir=C:/Bitnami/MEDIAW~1.1-0/mysql\data` What is the exact command line to use for innodb recovery flag? Thanks.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html  go to this url to check out innodb recovery flag options (note: this only recovers your data in a read only mode but you will be able to do a mysqldump).  However, based on what you said above I don't think your datadir is pointing to the right place.  can you please give the complete current path to where your mysql data is now?

Comment: I tried to follow your link but cannot find the command line to run from my shell. It does mention innodb_force_recovery = 1 but I don't understand if it's a command line option to mysqld.exe or something else.    As far as datadir not pointing to the right place: bitnami installation of mediawiki results in the following main folder: C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.24.1-0\  In it I can see mysql\ folder. In that folder there is the data\ folder. That data folder contains various files and other subfolders.

Comment: Also: The fresh install of bitnami contains ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and ibdata1.  The data I am trying to rescue only has ib_logfile1 (but has a bunch of mysql-bin files)

Comment: The inndodb_force_recovery is a parameter that is to be added to the my.cnf (in linux) and my.ini(in windows) file under the [mysqld] section. If the data you are trying to rescue does not have the ibdata1 file you have some serious problems. That file contains all metadata for innodb tables.  The mysql-bin files are used for replication purposes and can be disregarded in your case.

Comment: Hmm thanks for letting me know. I have some older backups of this wiki, that would contain ibdata1. Is there a way to merge it with this more recent state (albeit compromised)?

Comment: No, the metadata contained within the file (specifically the tablespaces) would be different. However, you may be able to use it in conjunction with the recovery flag. Note: recovery mode is read only. If you are successful with that approach you maybe able to do mysqldump and restore into fresh database.

Comment: So, just to verify: When I start, I should use the old database backup and do a dump? What command would you run first to be able to do a merge eventually?

Comment: I am not sure this will work.  My suggestion is to take ibdata1 file from older backup.  Set recovery_flag = 6 in my.ini file in corrupted database.  try to start mysql with data files from corrupted db, recovery flag set to 6, and ibdata1 file from old database backup.

Comment: Finally got to my retrospect backup of mediawiki. It's from March 2014. So, you said to take ibdata1 from it but what about ibdata0? ibdata 0 has date modified of March 22 2014 whereas ibdata1 only has 2013 Dec 28. Also, my March 2014 "data" folder has 83MB in it (Properties dialog of Windows) whereas the recent "rescue" is only 37MB. Is it still worth it for me to do what you said? I mean I'll try...what do I have to lose- I am just concerned that I will lose a lot of past data if I don't use the March 2014 backup.

Comment: At this point I am not sure.  You should only have an ibdata1 file. I am not sure if I can help you further.

Comment: I have given up on this - I am going to ask a different question now about getting access to my old database.